# iOS - Call Conference Duration not increase using linphone 4.4.0

Tags: swift, objective-c, voip, linphone, linphone-sdk

We used linphone for the VoIP app and faced issues in conference call duration. Duration not increased after merge call successfully.
Every time displays 00:00 but the call is generated successfully.We used below code for conference call

```
LinphoneAddress* linphoneAddress = linphone_core_interpret_url([LinphoneManager 
getLc], [username cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]);
 if (linphoneAddress == NULL) {
     return;

  }

  linphone_core_enter_conference(LC);
   LinphoneCall *call = linphone_core_invite_address(LC, linphoneAddress);

-(NSString *)getCallDuration
{
 LinphoneCore *lc = [LinphoneManager getLc];

int duration =
linphone_core_get_current_call(lc) ? 
linphone_call_get_duration(linphone_core_get_current_call(lc)) : 
0;
NSString *str_duration = [LinphoneUtils 
durationToString:duration];
return  str_duration;
 }
```

So anyone has any solution then please help us.

Thank you.

Comment: where / how are you retrieving and dispaying the call duration?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann,

Please check my question, edited with the getcallDuration method.
We are using this method for getting a call duration.